# Adding JSF to existing project J2EE in Netbeans

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, netbeans, crud

I have created a J2EE project, Now I want to generate `CRUD` from `MYSQL`.
Here is one option that looks fine by using JSF [Generating a JavaServer Faces 2.x CRUD Application from a Database](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/jsf20-crud.html).

My question is "Would this work with the existing code and navigation stuff?"

OR

Is there any other technique to generate CRUD code from MYSQL database automatically?

Comment: what is the existing code? what framework are you using? what types of views are you using?

Comment: I haven't used any framework. It's built using simple JSP pages and servlets.

Comment: then you'll have to replace all JSP pages with JSF pages; and all servlets with ManagedBeans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you migrate to JSF, you'll have to replace all JSP pages with JSF pages; and all servlets with ManagedBeans. Navigation, and everything related to the view is handled by JSF too.
If you already have many pages and servlets coded, and your only motivation of using JSF is to generate CRUD automatically, then I suggest that you create CRUD manually using the same technology you are currently using. On the other hand, using a framework makes things much easier for web development, so it's not a bad idea to use one. Other than JSF, you could use Spring MVC.